# Regex for input with numbers and commas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, validation, input

I'm trying to limit input data.

My goal:

- only two symbols per input allowed: numbers and a comma
- first symbol only number (zero or more)
- amount of numbers is unlimited (zero or more)
- a dangling comma is allowed but only one

Test cases:

- 1,2,4 - ок
- 1221,212,4121212 - ок
- ,2,3 - not ок
- 1,2,3, - ок
- 11,21111,31111, - ок

I've hade something like this but it doesn't work properly

`/^\d*(,\d*)*$/.test(value)`

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Try `/^\d+(?:,\d+)*,?$/` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/35pqrv/1/)).

Comment: Thanks!

But it keeps first letter in my input when I try to delete. Is it possible to make first letter zero or more?

Comment: Maybe you want to use `/^(?:\d+(?:,\d+)*,?)?$/`?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!

Could you please post your answer? I think it's very useful for other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
/^(?:\d+(?:,\d+)*,?)?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/35pqrv/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\d+(?:,\d+)*,?)?` - an optional non-capturing group:

  - `\d+` - one or more digits
  - `(?:,\d+)*` - zero or more sequences of a comma and one or more digits
  - `,?` - an optional comma
- `$` - end of string.